# Computing and representing centroids with K-means clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, centroid

I am currently stuck on a school exercise. The exercise is as follows.

> We will consider a subset of the wild faces data described in
>   berg2005[1]. Load the wildfaces data, Data/wildfaces using the loadmat
>   function. Each data object is a 40*40*3=4800 dimensional
>   vector, corresponding to a 3-color 40*40 pixels image. Compute a
>   k-means clustering of the data with K=10 clusters. Plot a few random
>   images from the data set as well as their corresponding cluster
>   centroids to see how they are represented.
>
> [1] Tamara L Berg, Alexander C Berg, Jaety Edwards, and DA Forsyth. Who's in the picture. Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems, 17:137-144, 2005.

Now to my question, how do I compute the centroids for one image? I am currently able to display the face and calculate centroids for the dataset. What I don't understand is, how do I know which centroids correspond to image 4 (as used in my code sample)? Do I have to calculate centroids for the entire dataset X or just X[4]? What steps do I need to take now, to 'plot the corresponding cluster centroids to see how they are represented'?

```
import scipy.io as spio
import sklearn.cluster as cl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

faces = spio.loadmat('Data/wildfaces.mat',squeeze_me=True)
X = faces['X']

Y = cl.k_means(X,10)
centroids = Y[0]
clusters = Y[1]

imshow(np.reshape(X[4,:],(3,40,40)).T)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have centroids. One per cluster.

You don't need to compute them, only display them.

Check the contents of Y

Comment: You are right, thanks. Looking back this is actually quite obvious.